# Setting all values in column to be same using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression

Using QGIS, I want to fill a whole column with the same "word".

Is there a faster way or an expression I can use in the field calculator instead of copy/paste?

In some layers I have more than a thousand attributes.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?  At least two of them have field calculators.

Comment: I'm using Q. I've been trying to google it but I've only seen videos where they copy paste. If only I could drag all the way down to fill the column or just use an expression, I don't know.

Comment: "I'm using Q" means QGIS? QGIS 2.something or QGIS 3? I've added the tag for you. I'll make the title more descriptive too... Hang on...

Comment: I'm using QGIS 2.18.15. Sorry I thought we weren't allowed to say software names

Comment: Software names and versions are encouraged! What isn't liked is "How can I do A using X or Y or Z?", which could be three questions. Your Q is fine, the title was a bit vague so I've improved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a layer in edit mode and the attribute table opened, choose the field from the left-hand drop-down (it says "abc thi" here), set the value (in the box after the expression editor "E" sign), and hit "update all":

[image]

Note that string values have to be in single quotes `'` in the expression box.

Switch edits off and save changes.